# How to use split function in spark scala

Tags: scala

I am supplying line by line to the program and each line consists of date in the format MM/DD/YYYY, how I can use split function here.

```
val data = line.split("/")
val year = data[2]
 println(year)
```

I am not getting any output can anyone explain me where I am wrong.

Comment: What is `data[2]`? It's not a type constructor, and it's not Java/C. Furthermore, is there any reason why this is tagged `apache-spark` and `bigdata`?

Comment: Because the snippet i kept is from scala and we will use scala in apache spark right?

Comment: There is no context in which `data[2]` would be valid scala syntax, unless it's in a string literal, a comment, or an identifier in backquotes. Array access with square brackets works in Java and other languages with C-inspired syntax. Where you are going to use the code snippet is irrelevant for the tags, only the content of the question is relevant for the tagging.

Answer (score 0):

You are not working on Java. Please look at the code snippet and make required changes in your code.

```
scala> val str = "12/05/2018"
str: String = 12/05/2018

scala> str.split("/")
res0: Array[String] = Array(12, 05, 2018)

scala> res0(2)
res1: String = 2018
```

So make below changes in your code:

```
val data = line.split("/")
val year = data(2)
println(year)
```

Comment: That's what I also did right.Can you go through once again and see that's what I also have written

Comment: a) it's not what you've written as you use `[2]` which won't compile b) presumably `line` doesn't contain what you think it does. Println that too, and check.